# Scikit-Learn FunctionTransformer in pipeline with no other functionality - not returning original data?

Tags: python-2.7, scikit-learn, pipeline

I am trying to run a custom transformer `FunctionTransformer()` within a Scikit-Learn pipeline in Python 2.7. I have used the example from the documentation [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/preprocessing/plot_function_transformer.html#example-preprocessing-plot-function-transformer-py). This example performs a PCA and then selects only the 2nd transformed component.i.e. transform a NumPy array X and extract the 2nd column of the transformed NumPy array.

The changes I have made to the code from the official documentation are below:

1. delete PCA() from pipeline
2. add 2 print statements to see X before pipeline and X after pipeline
3. removed train-test split - this way I am training with X and then transforming X
4. comment out all plotting code

Here is the full working code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import FunctionTransformer

def _generate_vector(shift=0.5, noise=15):
    return np.arange(1000) + (np.random.rand(1000) - shift) * noise

def generate_dataset():
    """
    This dataset is two lines with a slope ~ 1, where one has
    a y offset of ~100
    """
    return np.vstack((
        np.vstack((
            _generate_vector(),
            _generate_vector() + 100,
        )).T,
        np.vstack((
            _generate_vector(),
            _generate_vector(),
        )).T,
    )), np.hstack((np.zeros(1000), np.ones(1000)))
  
def all_but_first_column(X):
    return X[:, 1:]

def drop_first_component(X, y):
    """
    Create a pipeline with PCA and the column selector and use it to
    transform the dataset.
    """
    pipeline = make_pipeline(
        FunctionTransformer(all_but_first_column),
    )
    pipeline.fit(X,y)
    return pipeline.transform(X), y

if __name__ == '__main__':
    X, y = generate_dataset()
    print X[:20,:]
    X_transformed, y_transformed = drop_first_component(*generate_dataset())
    print X_transformed[:20,:]
```

When I run this code, I get the following output:

Before pipeline:

```
[[ -9.54109780e-01   1.00849257e+02]
 [ -6.44868525e+00   9.89713451e+01]
 [  6.00611903e+00   9.86368545e+01]
 [ -1.02307489e-01   9.91617270e+01]
 [  1.12423836e+01   1.04240711e+02]
 [  6.94957296e+00   1.09557543e+02]
 [  5.41042855e+00   1.09859950e+02]
 [  9.54984210e-01   1.03636786e+02]
 [  1.11194327e+01   1.06942524e+02]
 [  1.32146748e+01   1.16489221e+02]
 [  1.72316993e+01   1.16995924e+02]
 [  1.22797187e+01   1.08568249e+02]
 [  1.14360695e+01   1.06799741e+02]
 [  1.75291161e+01   1.13610682e+02]
 [  1.38768685e+01   1.07815267e+02]
 [  1.29773817e+01   1.12404830e+02]
 [  1.54218007e+01   1.11786074e+02]
 [  1.73923980e+01   1.19284226e+02]
 [  1.97373775e+01   1.16807048e+02]
 [  1.26896716e+01   1.26467393e+02]]
```

After pipeline:

```
[[  94.35392453]
 [ 107.08036958]
 [  96.42404642]
 [  96.07304368]
 [ 109.33207232]
 [ 102.67435761]
 [ 106.34131846]
 [ 108.45857447]
 [ 105.33376831]
 [ 107.79576699]
 [ 110.71367112]
 [ 116.73589447]
 [ 117.74629814]
 [ 112.48947773]
 [ 109.7573836 ]
 [ 121.95472733]
 [ 119.62476775]
 [ 120.0264124 ]
 [ 115.00315794]
 [ 120.60368954]]
```

From this Github [post](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/6249), it mentions that `FunctionTransformer()` can be used to do some simple things. I am hoping to only drop one column inside a pipeline.

The X before and after the pipeline are different. If all I want is for the pipeline to drop the last column of X, then should this pipeline return the same X before and after the pipeline?

**Additional information (if necessary):**

In my final application, I will need to use the transformer as the first step in the pipeline and then `PCA()` in the 2nd stop. Therefore, I am first testing the pipeline in this post with only the first step - `FunctionTransformer()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're making two calls to the `generate_dataset()` so the matrix being processed by your `drop_first_component` function is not `X`, `y`, but some newly generated data.

Passing the same `(X, y)` directly to `generate_dataset` fixes the problem:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
  X, y = generate_dataset()
  print X[:20, :]
  X_transformed, y_transformed = drop_first_component(X, y)
  print X_transformed[:20, :]
```

That said, I think using a pipeline stage here is totally overkill. You're importing a few extra libraries, including several additional lines of configuration and logic which is spread across three functions -- all for a calculation that does nothing other than a simple column select `X[:, 1:]`.

Comment: Thank you so much. That explains a lot to me! For the pipeline part, as I had mentioned in the Additional Information in the OP, I will next be adding a PCA step to the process so a pipeline would be helpful there. As it stands, you're right though, I don't need it. Thanks again.